# PHPStorm -> Sublime Text mac shortcut

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, phpstorm

I have googleing around for this, but have not found the answer. I have just gone from **sublime text** to **PHPStorm**. Is there any similar shortcuts for selecting variable(CMD+D), multiple cursor etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the equivalent to sublime text <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in PHPStorm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least in PHPStorm 8. It's Alt+j by default.